# Iterate over a matrix, sum over some rows and add the result to another array

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, matplotlib

Hi there I have the following matrix

```
 [[ 47  43  51  81  54  81  52  54  31  46]
  [ 35  21  30  16  37  11  35  30  39  37]
  [  8  17  11   2   5   4  11   9  17  10]
  [  5   9   4   0   1   1   0   3   9   3]
  [  2   7   2   0   0   0   0   1   2   1]
  [215 149 299 199 159 325 179 249 249 199]
  [ 27  49  24   4  21   8  35  15  45  25]
  [100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100]]
```

I need to iterate over the matrix summing all elements in rows 0,1,2,3,4 only
example: I need

```
  row_0_sum = 47+43+51+81....46
```

Furthermore I need to store each rows sum in an array like this

```
 [row0_sum, row1_sum, row2_sum, row3_sum, row4_sum]
```

So far I have tried this code but its not doing the job:

```
  mu = np.zeros(shape=(1,6))

  #get an average 
  def standardize_ratings(matrix):
 sum = 0
 for i, eli in enumerate(matrix):
     for j, elj in enumerate(eli):
        if(i<5):
         sum = sum + matrix[i][j]
         if(j==elj.len -1):
           mu[i] = sum
           sum = 0
           print "mu[i]="
           print mu[i]
```

This just gives me an `Error`:  `numpy.int32 object has no attribute 'len'`

So can someone help me. What's the best way to do this and which type of array in Python should I use to store this. Im new to Python but have done programming....

Thannks

Comment: I think you meant it to be `if j==eli.len-1:`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your data, `matrix`, a `numpy.ndarray` object, instead of a list of lists, and then just do `matrix.sum(axis=1)`.

```
>>> matrix = np.asarray([[ 47,  43,  51,  81,  54,  81,  52,  54,  31,  46],
  [ 35,  21,  30,  16,  37,  11,  35,  30,  39,  37],
  [  8,  17,  11,   2,   5,   4,  11,   9,  17,  10],
  [  5,   9,   4,   0,   1,   1,   0,   3,   9,   3],
  [  2,   7,   2,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,   2,   1],
  [215, 149, 299, 199, 159, 325, 179, 249, 249, 199],
  [ 27,  49,  24,   4,  21,   8,  35,  15,  45,  25],
  [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]])

>>> print matrix.sum(axis=1)
[ 540  291   94   35   15 2222  253 1000]
```

To get the first five rows from the result, you can just do:

```
>>> row_sums = matrix.sum(axis=1)
>>> rows_0_through_4_sums = row_sums[:5]
>>> print rows_0_through_4_sums
[540 291  94  35  15]
```

Or, you can alternatively sub-select only those rows to begin with and only apply the summation to them:

```
>>> rows_0_through_4 = matrix[:5,:]
>>> print rows_0_through_4.sum(axis=1)
[540 291  94  35  15]
```

Some helpful links will be:

[NumPy for Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html), if you are familiar with these things in Matlab/Octave

[Slicing/Indexing in NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: It looks like it's numpy already.  A list of lists would print with commas in it

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true. But I wanted to cover it just in case.

Comment: Also, you might want to show the user how to slice the first 5 rows out of the list as it looks like those are the only ones OP wants to sum over ...